# Suggesting migration of off-topic questions to other Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, feature-request, migration

Just a while ago I encountered an off-topic question ([“Installation complete” msg when opening tor link in Android](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/623/114)). I wanted to suggest closing it and migrating it to the [Super User](https://superuser.com/) site but *Closing > Off-Topic > Migration* suggests only *meta.tor.stackexchange.com* for migration.

How can we add other sites to this menu?
If someone has the rights to extend the menu can the [Super User](https://superuser.com/) site be added?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you see a problem but it doesnt fit any of the existing flag/close reasons, you should raise a custom flag i.e. flag for moderator attention with a clear description of the problem (why it should be migrated, and to where).

[image]

As far as editing the list of off-topic close reasons/migration sites is concerned, the mods, once appointed, will have the ability to edit the options available under off-topic.